# How to set up a decimal range [0.5,1] step [0.05] with NoUiSlider

Tags: nouislider

I am using NoUiSlider 8.1.0 and though the value returned is a correctly a decimal with two places, the values shown in the scale as:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
1           1           1             1           1             1
```

instead of:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
0.5        0.6          0.7           0.8         0.9           1
```

How can I achieve the desired scale?

This is my code:

```
 noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start:0.5,
    step: 0.05,
    range:{
        'min':[0.5],
        'max':[1]
    },
    connect:'lower',
    pips:{
        mode:'steps',
        density:4

    },
    format: wNumb({decimals:2}),

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `format` options to pips and it will work!

```
noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start:0.5,
    step: 0.05,
    range:{
        'min':[0.5],
        'max':[1]
    },
    connect:'lower',
    pips:{
        mode:'steps',
        density:4,
        format: wNumb({ decimals: 2 }),
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this just costed me 30min to find but finally it works. THANKS!